# Emacs installation package error

Tags: bash, debian, shell, package-management, emacs

I'm trying to install emacs on my debian jessie, but I have the following package error,

```
thinkpad-keith@debian-keith:~$ sudo apt install emacs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-talloc : Breaks: python-samba (< 2:4.3.6+dfsg-2) but 2:4.2.10+dfsg-0+deb8u3 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I've searched online, but none seems to have this problem.

Comment: Do `apt-get update` first. There is no version 2:4.2.10+dfsg-0+deb8u3 of python-samba in debian currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the error message is not directly related to the installation of emacs, but is caused by an earlier operation.

Your currently-installed `python-talloc` package seems to require a newer version of `python-samba` package than is available on Debian Jessie. This suggests you might currently have a version of `python-talloc` that is not intended for Jessie.

The "Breaks:" dependency on your `python-talloc` is exactly the same as the current version of the package on Debian Stretch has. So you might actually have Stretch's version of `python-talloc` installed. Please run this command to identify the exact version of `python-talloc` you currently have:

```
dpkg-query -s python-talloc
```

If the "Version:" line says "2.1.8-1", that's the version for Stretch. The up-to-date version for Jessie is "2.1.2-0+deb8u1" at the time of this writing.

This might have happened accidentally if you had the Debian version in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` specified as `stable` instead of `jessie`. Unfortunately this used to be the default for the Debian installer, at least the last time I checked. When Debian 9 "Stretch" was released on June 17 2017, the alias "stable" switched from "jessie" to "stretch" and "jessie" got the alias "oldstable" instead.

If you are using a stable version of Debian and don't change your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file to point to the actual release nickname instead of `stable` before the *next* stable version is released, this can easily happen.

If you want to stay with Jessie, you should now ensure your `/etc/apt/sources.list` points to "jessie" or "oldstable" package sources only, and then you should identify and downgrade any packages of Stretch that have been installed onto your system along with any updates. It looks like `python-talloc` is one of them.

If you want to upgrade to Stretch, you should first read the upgrade instructions in the release notes of Stretch.

Comment: I changed the alias from "stable" to "oldstable" in  `/etc/apt/sources.list`  and everything was solved.

Comment: @Keith, you should change the “oldstable” alias to “jessie” explicitly, otherwise you’ll run into the same kind of problem when the next release of Debian comes out.